# SSRS Excel tab name for first group

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I'm working with `SSRS 2008 R2` to create a report that will be exported to `Excel`.

I have two tablixes: the first showing all of my data, the second showing it grouped by category. I have a page break after the first tablix.  In the second tablix, I have page breaks between each instance of a group, and I've defined the `PageName` to be `Fields!Category.Value`.

This works to make the sheets named whatever category is showing on the sheet, *except for the first sheet of the group*.  That sheet is named the same as the overall sheet.  Or, if I define the `PageName` of the second tablix, I can give it a different name, but it's static and doesn't reflect the group that is on that sheet.

So my question is: is there a way to force the first sheet of a tablix to take the name of the group?

In addition to the basic steps I've taken above, I've tried:

1. In the `Group Properties`, checking the `"Also at the start of a group"` box.  For some reason, though, this does nothing but make my report infinitely long and the data never shows (I think it just puts an infinite number of breaks before the group).
2. In the properties of the second tablix, instead of having a static `PageName`, trying to get the first Category by doing something like `=FIRST(Fields!Category.Value, "Tablix2")` as the expression.  This works sometimes, but it seems the order isn't guaranteed, so sometimes I label a sheet that has one category with the name of another category.

Am I missing something obvious?  Or is there a not-so-obvious workaround?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried setting the PageBreak BreakLocation of the 2nd table to **Start**? If that doesn't work, try putting the table in a rectangle.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions!  I did try putting the BreakLocation at **Start**.  If I do it at the Start of the Tablix, it still has the name problem.  If I do it at the Start of the group, it gives me the infinitely long report problem (I'm guessing it puts a break before the group, then the start of the group is moved, so it puts another break, etc.).

Putting it in a rectangle still has the same problem.